# Raspberry Pi 2 model B CPU temperature

Tags: raspbmc, osmc

I just got my Rpi2 model B yesterday and I installed `osmc` with some plugins just to see how it works. This is my first single board computer.

After a few hours of use I noticed the CPU temp was 49-50 Celsius degrees.  Is this normal?

Today I "overclocked" the system CPU speed @ 1GHz and shared a little more ram to video 320 MB.  Now the temp is 44-45 Celsius degrees.

Are those temps normal?

Comment: They seem reasonable to be.  There can not be a normal as what is a normal ambient temperature?  It will vary country to country and season to season.

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed discussion from a forum is linked here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=2758&p=256110

But, in short, 85 degrees Celsius is where you need to start worrying and you have acceptable running temperatures.  If you're in a really cold area and have a fan on it and it's running at temps like that, I'd venture to say something is wrong, but otherwise you're fine.

Also, people have tried to overheat the pi and failed.

> by Gert van Loo » Wed Aug 05, 2015 7:03 am
>   I was responsible for the temperature testing of the PI-2.
>   This is always based on a few sample and only a short time but I did manage
>   to run a Pi-2 in an oven measuring the on-die temperature as 150C. But only for a short time.
>   It still worked fine several weeks later.
>   In fact I had some system crashes at lower temperatures which turned out to be the SD-card giving up
>   when the oven reached ~100C. I had to try several cards to see which one to use.